# Infusionsoft OAuth callback SSL error PHP

Tags: php, apache, api, ssl-certificate, infusionsoft

my problem is this:

Ive went to developer.infusionsoft.com to get the PHP-SDK helper library for Infusionsoft API integration.
I installed it via composer. i have the vendor(folder)which, appears after composer finish.

over the tutorials, vendor folder is very significant so i think im on the right path of things

my code for using the api is this

```
function loadInfusionsoft($callback) {
    $data = array();
    $data['status'] = "unsuccessfull";
    try {
        $infusionsoft = new \Infusionsoft\Infusionsoft(array(
            'clientId' => 'CLIENTID',
            'clientSecret' => 'SECRETKEY',
            'redirectUri' => $callback,
        ));
//        If the serialized token is available in the session storage, we tell the SDK
//        to use that token for subsequent requests.
        if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
            $infusionsoft->setToken(unserialize($_SESSION['token']));
        }

// If we are returning from Infusionsoft we need to exchange the code for an
// access token.
        if (isset($_GET['code']) and ! $infusionsoft->getToken()) {
            $infusionsoft->requestAccessToken($_GET['code']);
        }

        if ($infusionsoft->getToken()) {
// Save the serialized token to the current session for subsequent requests
            $_SESSION['token'] = serialize($infusionsoft->getToken());
        } else {
            $href = $infusionsoft->getAuthorizationUrl();
            $data['status'] = "successfull";
            $data["href"] = $href;
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
    return $data;
```

please bear with me, i am new to this, so i have a vague clue on what is happening. i got this code on the infusionsoft tutorial(git). and on the middle of understanding things, i got an error.

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

i didn't get that error right away though. on what i understand,

- it will skip all the if statements and will land on the else statement.
- on else statement, i will be given an href link for the infusionsoft authentication. most probably an href value of `<a>`.
- on the page, clicking on that link, will go to infusionsoft loggedin
- after successful logged in, it will redirect to my localhost (because of the callback variable) with GET variables (which are scope, and code)
- It will call this function again.
- i believe it will enter the `if isset($_GET['code'])` statement
- got the error

  cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
- on my researches, i need a certificate.
- on looking on the vendor folder(infusionsoft PHP SDK) i see that
  there is a `cacert.pem`    file.. on my research, that is a
  certificate file
- I searched how to use it but i always saw about crt and cert files.

and im stucked.

whats the next step? searched infusionsoft community but no luck.

i believe its not an infusionsoft issue but a mere misconfiguration on my end.
anyone?

Comment: have you got a copy of cacert.pem on your system? you can download from curl.haxx.se ( https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem )

Comment: @RamRaider yes i have it on the infusionsoft's PHP-SDK but i dont know how to use it. as indicated on my statements above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just want to share. after few trials and errors.

its just really a simple error (problem is i am not quite knowledgeable to this)

on php.ini file, add the path to the cacert.pem like this.

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\path\to\cacert.pem"
```

note that curl.cainfo must have an absolute path.